SUM(cond) and COUNT(cond) with HAVING Clause behave differently
I need to write a query to find customers who bought products "Bread" and "Milk" but did not buy the product "Eggs". If I replace SUM with COUNT, the below query does not work as intended. I am not able to understand why
SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name
FROM customers c
JOIN orders o
USING (customer_id)
GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.customer_name
HAVING SUM(o.product_name = 'Bread')>0 AND SUM(o.product_name = 'Milk')>0 AND SUM(o.product_name = 'Eggs')=0
ORDER BY customer_name

If I use SUM and COUNT in SELECT, it seems like COUNT works and SUM does not which is the opposite. But why does it not work for above query. Appreciate any help. Thanks
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(product_name = 'Bread') AS bread_orders,  SUM(product_name = 'Bread') AS bread_orders_1
FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_id;


The source of the confusion is the following call to COUNT on a conditional expression:
COUNT(product_name = 'Bread')

This is equivalent to:
COUNT(CASE WHEN product_name = 'Bread' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

It is the case that COUNT() counts the values 0 or 1 both as 1.  To get the behavior you expect, the ELSE condition should return null:
COUNT(CASE WHEN product_name = 'Bread' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)

which can be shortened to:
COUNT(CASE WHEN product_name = 'Bread' THEN 1 END)

However, on MySQL, I prefer using SUM() as you have been doing:
SUM(product_name = 'Bread')

Here, the SUM() function also will be passed 0 or 1, but only the latter will increase the count.

Thanks Tim. ALso, Does COUNT(cond) & SUM(cond) behave differently in HAVING & SELECT statement?

@user25856037 No, they don't, however if you're using them differently then the behavior can be different.
